Running cleanup method before migrate:fresh to remove old images from storage
I would like to cleanup the locally seeded storage images when running php artisan migrate:fresh --seed.
I noticed that all the database tables get dropped before the seeders even start. So my method for cleaning up local storage images was never touched:
private function cleanLocalFileSystem()
{
    $files = File::all();
    $files->each(function (File $file) {
        $this->fileController->destroy($file->id); // removes associated files from storage.
    });
}

So there must be a way to clear out theses images at the start of running the migrate:fresh --seed command.
Right?

I suggest you create a custom artisan command on your project since Laravel may not have a direct command to handle it. So the idea is so allow you clean up before you migrate.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/artisan#registering-commands
php artisan make:command CleanupThenMigrate

Next, you write your logic for the created command. Go to app/Console/Commands/CleanupThenMigrate.php
**

<?php
    namespace App\Console\Commands;
    use Illuminate\Console\Command;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    
class CleanupThenMigrate extends Command
    {
        protected $signature = 'app:cleanup-then-migrate';
        protected $description = '';
        /**
         * Execute the console command.
         */
        public function handle()
        {
            //
            $this->info('Cleaning up local storage images...');
            $this->cleanLocalFileSystem();
            // Run migrations and seeders
            $this->info('Running migrate:fresh...');
            $this->call('migrate:fresh');
            $this->info('Seeding the database...');
            $this->call('db:seed');
            $this->info('Hala Madrid! All local images have been deleted. Migration and Seeding is complete too!');
        }
        private function cleanLocalFileSystem()
        {
            // Define your local storage path
            $storagePath = storage_path('app/public');
            // Delete all files in the storage path
            $getFiles = File::allFiles($storagePath);
            foreach ($getFiles as $file) {
                File::delete($file);
            }
        }
    }

**
Next, run php artisan app:cleanup-then-migrate
I hope this helps.

This is a excellent answer. I ended up solving this issue before your answer came in. So I will also post my solution for those interested.

I ended up solving this issue myself before the solultion of @mamaye came in.
I made a .bat file in my Apache bin directory named refreshdb. These are it's contents:
php artisan storage:clear
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed

Then I made the command with php artisan make:command ClearStorage.
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\FileController;
use App\Models\File;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Intervention\Image\Exception\NotFoundException;

class ClearStorageCommand extends Command {

    protected $signature = 'storage:clear';
    protected $description = 'Clears all seeder images from storage';
    private FileController $fileController;

    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();

       $this->fileController = new FileController();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            $this->cleanLocalFileSystem();
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $this->error("Failed to clear storage with message: " . $exception->getMessage());
        }

        $this->info('Successfully cleared storage');
    }

    private function cleanLocalFileSystem()
    {
        $files = File::all();

        $files->each(function (File $file) {
            $success = $this->fileController->destroy($file->id);

            if (!$success) {
                throw new NotFoundException('Could not clear file: ' . $file->path . '/' . $file->name);
            }
        });
    }
}

Now I can simply run the refreshdb command in the terminal and all is well.
Again, this is simular to mamaye's solution but it worked for me.

If you store uploaded files in 'storage/app/images', and the info about them in table 'images' you can easily remove all your test files and rows (including orphaned files) like this:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

File::cleanDirectory(storage_path('app/images'));
DB::table('images')->truncate();

